# Specify version in the question

Tags: discussion, support

If my answer involves deprecated or added commands, what should I do?

Give two different answers to help current and the future users? Or give an answer hoping that the version is the right one?

In my opinion users should specify version of the software they are using, so they can receive a precise answer.

Comment: Yea, i mean, it would be great if askers always specified a version, however, that also means that the question essentially has a soft kill timer. It discourages users from posting up to date answers or updating their existing answers later when things change. As an answerer, you can post the answer for multiple versions in a single answer pretty easily, regardless of whether or not the asker is asking for it.

Comment: To add to what @KevinB said, answers are supposed to withstand the test of time.  As best as it can, anyways.  An answer in the latest version is likely to be far more useful than one from an older version.

Comment: What are some examples of commands?

Comment: @PeterMortensen ex. `split` in php (removed in php 7) or `RANK()` in mysql (added in version 8)

Comment: @KevinB I think the soft kill timer is good. Maybe in a year there is a better solution. Not always the solution with an old version is easier.

Comment: We don't *want* soft kill timers, @Alberto.  We're here to build a giant repository of knowledge; answers will get outdated, but we want content that lasts for years, no matter if they're for old, rarely used languages or versions, or the next hot thing.  Deliberately making content obsolete goes against that principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume they are using the latest.

You aren't answering OP's question, you are answering the question for the people of the future that will land in that question. Offer the best answer for that user. BTW, you don't need to have the version to provide an working solution for the future reader either. You don't know what version would they be using in a year from now.

Answer (score 4):

Users certainly should specify the version - however my view is that you should write a single answer which contains both approaches.  This means that users who came along with essentially the same problem (but a different version), can still use your answer.

I often see this in questions about C++ ("from C++14 you can ..., but in earlier versions you have to ..."), Python ("Python 3 ..."), and git.

If the answer is *completely* different, then don't answer until the user has clarified which version they are using.

Comment: This is not scalable over long time periods. What happened in the Python tag is that common questions which are still topical for Python 3 but have a different answer will get a new answer which points out how this changed from Python 2. Very often, the old - and now obsolete - answer will be accepted, and have a significant amount of upvotes. The best we can hope for is that new visitors will be aware of this situation, and pay attention.

Comment: @tripleee that's why some asks for SE to not pin the accepted answer to the top.